# Django: Pass object parameters to return results in html modal view

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-urls

Currently I'm using **non-hardcoded urls** to redirect users to a page with similar products by matching a barcode number.

**views.py**

```
def ItemView(request, barcode):
    template_name = "TESTcategories.html"
    products = Product.objects.filter(barcode=barcode)

    context = {
             'products': products,
    }


    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^item/(?P<barcode>[0-9]+)$', ItemView, name='ItemView'),
```

**items.html**

```
<h3 class="product-title"><a href="{% url 'ItemView' result.object.barcode %}">{{result.object.title}}</a></h3>
```

I'm passing the barcode arguments through based on the URL pattern. Can I achieve a similar effect but for a 'quick view' option that will launch a pop up modal view. 
This is my potential modal:

**partials/modal.html**

```
 <!-- Large Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalLarge" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Quick Item Compare</h4>
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          <!-- Product in modal -->
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">

               {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>{{result.object.title}}</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>£{{result.object.price}}</th>
                    <th class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-btn btn-success" href="{{result.object.url}}">Visit Site</a></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {% endfor %}

              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT: In my modal.html the results are iterating against page_obj.object_list as I am using djang-haystack with elastic-search.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. What's not working? If `modal.html` is part of an HTML Django template (using `{% include %}`), then you need a view a to render that template. Which view is that and what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I'm not refreshing the page when I click the button to open up the modal view, so I'm not able to pass the barcode arguments to a view. Unlike, when I click the actual url redirect.

Comment: I want my modal to be dynamically filtered based on the result objects barcode.

Comment: But on which page are you showing the modal? If it's on a page where you already have the item(s) with barcode, you can add the object list(s) to your context in your view so it's already there (and hide the modal with javascript until the user clicks on it). If not and the content of the modal depends on some user input on the page, then you probably want to make a javascript XHR request (that includes the barcode in the URL) and triggers your django view to return JSON. Instead of being a django template, your javascript populates your modal's divs.